# How to embed local page as iframe in cordova android app

Tags: android, cordova

I cannot seem to embed a local page "page2.hyml as an Iframe in my Cordova  "index.html" page.
I am successfully able to embed an external URL as an Iframe though.

Is there a way to do that?